# How to save custom objects inside of an array that holds more custom objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdata

I have an array that is broken down like this:

```
PersonArray
    PersonObject
       1. NSstring (personsName)
       2. NSMutableArray (EventsObject)
```

I am able to save this array with the code below:

```
NSMutableArray *archiveArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:mutableDataArray.count];
for (BC_Person *personObject in mutableDataArray)
{
    NSData *personEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:personObject];
    [archiveArray addObject:personEncodedObject];
}

NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userData setObject:archiveArray forKey:@"personDataArray"];
[userData synchronize];
```

What I am stuck on is: If I add an object to the `NSMutableArray` inside of the `Person` object, do I also have to turn that array of object (`EventsObject`) into `NSData`?

(I would assume I do, but I can't seem to figure out how to target that array of objects (`EventsObject`) to convert inside the `PersonArray`.

I hope I am explaining this in a manner that is easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray` and some other classes implement the `NSCoding` protocol. So you can simplify your code to:

```
NSData *personData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mutableDataArray];
NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userData setObject:personData forKey:@"personDataArray"];
[userData synchronize];
```

And for any objects to be archived you implement the `NSCoding` protocol. So for `BC_Person` it could look like this (I do not know the class so I am making up some properties as an example):

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:self.firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.lastName forKey:@"lastName"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.eventObjects forKey:@"eventObjects"];
}
```

In this example `self.eventObjects` would be an array of objects of your `EventsObject` class. The array knows how to encode itself, and for `EventsObject` you implement another `-encodeWithCoder:` method.

And to unarchive you reverse the process.